# Сброс пароля администратора в самописной конфигурации 1С на SQL

Tags: sql, 1с

Собственно нужно сбросить пароль в 1с на sql (самописная база). Есть доступ к базе через windows management studio.

В нете есть способы для сброса 8.1 Например:

1С при работе на SQL хранит список пользователей в двух местах: в таблице v8users и в файле users.usr который бинарно расположен в таблице Params.

Надо платформу думать что в базе нет ни одного пользователя. Для этого необходимо переименовать таблицу v8users и строчку с файлом users.usr. Открываем SQL Server Management Studio логинимся и создаем запрос к базе данных с содержанием:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'v8users', 'v8users_old'
GO
UPDATE Params
SET FileName = 'users.usr_old'
WHERE FileName = 'users.usr'
GO
```

После этого открываем базу данных в конфигураторе и видим что платформа не спрашивает пользователя и пароль, при этом в SQL Server будет заново создана таблица v8users. Теперь чтобы всех пользователей вернуть обратно не закрывая конфигуратора выполним в SQL Server Management Studio запрос:

```
DROP TABLE v8users
GO
EXEC sp_rename 'v8users_old', 'v8users'
GO
UPDATE Params
SET FileName = 'users.usr'
WHERE FileName = 'users.usr_old'
GO
```

После выполнения запроса в списке пользователей появяться все пользователи, останеться только найти нужного и изменить ему пароль.

Но таблицы v8users вообще не существует в нашей базе. В таблице Params есть строка users.usr_old. Но почему она old? Видимо ранее кто то, что то пытался сделать. Может быть пароли хранятся в другой таблице? Может быть программист перенес пароли в другое место? Или все статьи по сбросу пароля только для 8.2???? Непонятно... Прошу помощи.

Comment: Проверь есть ли таблица Usersv8 также посмотри dbo.Params строчка users.usr

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощение. Оказывается все срабатывает не смотря на ошибки...